# Would ordering of documents when indexing improve Elasticsearch search performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-performance

I'm indexing about 40M documents into Elasticsearch. It's usually a one off data load and then we do run queries on top. There's no further updates to the index itself. However the default settings of Elasticsearch isn't getting me the throughput I expected.

So in long list of things to tune and verify, I was wondering whether ordering by a business key would help improve the search throughput. All our analysis queries use this key and it is indexed as a keyword already and we do a filter on it like below,

```json
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "type": "cross_fields",
                  "query":"store related query", 
                  "minimum_should_match": "30%",      
                  "fields": [ "field1^5", "field2^5", "field3^3", "field4^3", "firstLine", "field5", "field6", "field7"] 
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "businessKey": "storename"
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

This query is run in a bulk fashion about 20M times in a matter of few hours. Currently I cannot go past 21k/min. But that could be because of various factors. Any tips to improve performance for this sort of work flow (load once and search a lot) would be appreciated.

However I'm particularly interested to know if I could order the data first by business key when I'm indexing so that data for that businessKey lives within one single Lucene segment and hence the lookup would be quicker. Is that line of thoughts correct? Is this something ES already does given that it's keyword term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very good performance optimization use-case and as you already mentioned there will be a list of performance optimization which you need to do.

I can see, you are already building the query correctly that is that filtering the records based on `businessKey` and than search on remaining docs, this way you are already utilizing the [filter-cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) of elasticsearch.

As you have huge number of documents ~40M docs, it doesn't make sense to put all of them  in single segments, default max size of segment is 5 GB and beyond that
[merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html) process will be blocked on segments, hence its almost impossible for you to have just 1 segment for your data.

I think couple of things which you can do is:

1. Disable refresh interval when you are done with ingesting your data and preparing index for search.
2. As you are using the filters, your request_cache should be used and you should monitor the cache usage when you are querying and monitor how many times results are coming from cache.

```
GET your-index/_stats/request_cache?human
```

3. Read throughput is more when you have more replicas and if you have nodes in your elasticsearch cluster makes sure these nodes, have replicas of your ES index.
4. Monitor the search queues on each nodes and make sure its not getting exhausted otherwise you will not be able to increase the throughput, refer [threadpools in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) for more info

You main issue is around throughput and you want to go beyond current limit of 21k/min, so it requires a lot of index and cluster configuration optimization as well and I have written [short tips to improve search performance](https://opster.com/blogs/improve-elasticsearch-search-performance/) please refer them and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That's really good list of things to cover, I've already started running 1 shard and 4 replicas, we have 5 data nodes. Throughput looks to have improved, still running tests to get exact numbers. I did hit the error with thread pool when we had 5 primary shard 1 replica for each of them. `rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable@279f7db6 on QueueResizingEsThreadPoolExecutor..queue capacity = 1000, min queue capacity = 1000, max queue capacity = 1000, frame size = 2000, targeted response rate = 1s, task execution EWMA = 21.1ms, adjustment amount = 50`

Comment: @opensourcegeek thanks for your kind words, your this rejected queue exception is def blocking you to go past your current throughput, hence you need to fine-tune the queue capacity and add more nodes and horizontally scale your index to get more throughput apart from in general perf improvement tips which I shared.

Comment: I had that queue issue when I had 5 primary and 1 replica for each = 10 shards in 5 data nodes. Once I switched to 1 primary and 5 replicas I've not seen that problem and the throughput has gone up per node (to 32k/min). I think at this point it's probably upstream flow where it blocks although I don't see any cache hits for request. Switching off refresh interval hasn't made a lot of difference too probably cause there's only one shard?

Comment: @opensourcegeek this is almost 50% gain which you got   and for refresh_interval it won't make difference if you are just getting the search aka read requests, its not depend on the shard number. although now it could be due to upstream you are not getting better throughput but I am more curious about the cache usage. and would advise you to ask a follow-up questions on cache usage so that we can discuss it there dedocatly :)

Comment: Thanks - one thing to say is the scoring has changed in subtle ways between 1 primary 5 replicas to 3 primary and 0 replicas. Will scoring change even if it's one off single data load and queries are ran later? No updates to primary after replicas are created

Comment: @opensourcegeek could you please ask a dedicate question on this and will be more than happy to explain it in detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is faster with more shards(& segments) and Querying is faster with less shards (& segments).
If you are doing a one-time load you can do a force merge of segments post indexing and also think about adding more replicas post indexing to distribute search and increase throughput.

If each query is going to be specific to a business key, segregating data while indexing and creating one index per documents related to a business key might help. And similarly while querying direct the query to specific index pertaining to the business key being queried.

Going through below links might help

[Tune for Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-search-speed.html)

[Tune for Indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html)

[Optimise Search](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-searches)

Comment: The business keys are not going to be huge (between 1 - 1000 instances). Imagine shops in postcode, in some postcode there might be a large number of them and in some postcodes there might be just one. Postcode here if it's ordered then all the shops in the postcode will require just one segment to be read was my idea.