# Compute percentile with collapsing by user

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-performance

Let says I have an index where I save a million of tweets (original object). I want to get the 90th percentile users based on the number of followers.
I know there is the aggregation "percentile" to do this, but my problem is that ElasticSearch use all documents so I have some users that tweet a lot who noise my calculation.
I want to isolate all unique user then compute the 90th.
The other constraint is that I want to do this in only one or two requests to keep the response lower than 500ms.

I have tried a lot of things and I was able to do this with "scripted_metric" but when my dataset exceed 100k of tweets the performances go down criticaly.

Any advice ?

Additionnal infos :

- My index store orginal tweets & retweets based on user search queries
- The index is mapped with a dynamic template mapping (No problem with this)
- The index contains approximatly 100M
- Unfortunately, "top hits" aggregation doesn't accept sub-aggs.

The request I try to achieve is :

```
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user.id"    <--- I want this effect on aggregation
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "metadatas.clientId": {
              "value": projectId
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "metadatas.blacklisted": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "publishedAt": {
              "gte": "now-90d/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "twitter": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "user.followers_count",
        "percents": [95]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180300/4039431 and see if it was helpful, also please share the index details, query and cluster info like the one which is shared in discussed in same thread

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figure out to find a workaround.

In percentile aggregation, I can use a script. I use params variable to hold unique keys then return preceding _score.

Without the complete explanation of the computation, I cannot fine tune the behavior of my script. But the result is good enough for me.

```
"aggs": {
    "unique":{
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "collapse_profile"
      }
    },
    "thresholds":{
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "user.followers_count",
        "percents": [90], 
        "script": {
          "source": """
            if(params.keys == null){
              params.keys = new HashMap();
            }
            
            def key = doc['user.id'].value;
            def value = doc['user.followers_count'].value;
            
            if(params.keys[key] == null){
              params.keys[key] = _score;
              return value;
            }
            return _score;
          """,
          "lang": "painless"
        }
      }
    }    
  }
```